# C++: wrap enum in a class

Tags: c++, enums

I want to wrap an enum in a class so I can attach methods to it. I also want that sizeof(CommandType) == sizeof(U8). I made the following experiment:

```
class CommandType
{
public:
    enum knownTypes;
    CommandType()             { cmdType = CmdType0; }
    CommandType(knownTypes v) { cmdType = (knownTypes)v; }
    operator const U8()       { return cmdType; }
    bool operator ==(CommandType v2) { return cmdType == v2; }
    int f(int x) { return 22; }
    enum knownTypes : U8 { CmdType0, CmdType1, CmdType2, CmdType3, CmdType4 };
private:
    knownTypes cmdType;
};

int main()
{
    CommandType ct = CommandType::CmdType2; // Preproc: no suitable constructor exists to convert from "CommandType::knowntypes" to "CommandType"
    ct = CommandType::CmdType1; // Preproc: no operator matches these operands; operand types are: CommandType = CommandType::knowntypes
    const CommandType ct1c = CommandType::CmdType3; // Preproc: no suitable constructor exists to convert from "CommandType::knowntypes" to "CommandType"
    CommandType ct2 = ct1c;
    const CommandType ct3c = ct1c;
    int ctf = ct.f(0);
    int szct = sizeof(CommandType);
    if (ct2 == ct) // ok
        while (0);
    if (ct2 == ct1c) // ok
        while (0);
    if (ct3c == ct1c) // Preproc: no operator matches these operands; operand types are: CommandType = CommandType::knowntypes
                      // Compiler: no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const CommandType'
        while (0);
```

I get some preprocessor problems and even a compilation error as shown in the comments. How to solve them?

Comment: `enum knownTypes;` is ill-formed. "Old style" enums can't be forward declared. This can't be the code you really have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a few fixes, I turned OP's code into something I could compile.

These are the issues I solved:

1. Fixing `enum knownTypes` as mentioned by StoryTeller.
2. `U8` unknown. → `typedef uint8_t U8;`
3. Fixing the `operator==()`:

   `bool operator ==(CommandType v2) { return cmdType == v2.cmdType; }`
4. Fixing the `operator==()` const-ness:

   `bool operator ==(CommandType v2) const { return cmdType == v2.cmdType; }`

Afterwards, I got only two warnings which are IMHO non-relevant.

```
#include <cstdint> // needed for uint8_t

typedef uint8_t U8;

class CommandType
{
public:
    enum knownTypes : U8 { CmdType0, CmdType1, CmdType2, CmdType3, CmdType4 };
    CommandType()             { cmdType = CmdType0; }
    CommandType(knownTypes v) { cmdType = (knownTypes)v; }
    operator const U8()       { return cmdType; }
    bool operator ==(CommandType v2) const { return cmdType == v2.cmdType; }
    int f(int x) { return 22; }
private:
    knownTypes cmdType;
};

int main()
{
    CommandType ct = CommandType::CmdType2; // ??? Preproc: no suitable constructor exists to convert from "CommandType::knowntypes" to "CommandType"
    ct = CommandType::CmdType1; // ??? Preproc: no operator matches these operands; operand types are: CommandType = CommandType::knowntypes
    const CommandType ct1c = CommandType::CmdType3; // ??? Preproc: no suitable constructor exists to convert from "CommandType::knowntypes" to "CommandType"
    CommandType ct2 = ct1c;
    const CommandType ct3c = ct1c;
    int ctf = ct.f(0);
    int szct = sizeof(CommandType);
    if (ct2 == ct) // ok
        while (0);
    if (ct2 == ct1c) // ok
        while (0);
    if (ct3c == ct1c) // !!! Preproc: no operator matches these operands; operand types are: CommandType = CommandType::knowntypes
                      // Compiler: no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const CommandType'
        while (0);
    return 0;
}
```

<kbd>[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9d07b5e0f159a755)</kbd>

I remarked issues of OP with

- `???` which I didn't fix explicitly (but may be implicitly)
- `!!!` which are solved by the above fixes.

---

**Note:**

When I define `operator==()` then I define `operator!=()` as well (as I like symmetry). This can be done easily based on the existing:

```
bool operator!=(CommandType v2) const { return !operator==(v2); }
```

This is in so far maintenance friendly, as fixes in `operator==()` will cover `operator!=()` as well "automatically".